# How to divide data to half while using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've have some data and i'm able to compile this data to `div` with using `ng-repeat`. I'm trying to divide them to 2 columns and cound't find a way to build it.

Here is my example: **[( jsFiddle )](http://jsfiddle.net/1fch1221/)**

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="left">
      <div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.value}}</div>
      <!-- i've tried filter and failed -->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
      {value: "a"},
      {value: "b"},
      {value: "c"},
      {value: "d"},// trying to divide from here
      {value: "e"},// and show the last part in other column
      {value: "f"},
      {value: "g"},
      {value: "h"}
  ];
}
```

Comment: Like so http://jsfiddle.net/1fch1221/3/ ?

Comment: Yeah, why do you restrict yourself with a single scope variable?

Comment: @Shomz data came to me from back end like this.

Comment: But nothing stops you from spreading the data yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use two variables, like so

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
      {value: "a"},
      {value: "b"},
      {value: "c"},
      {value: "d"},// trying to divide from here
      {value: "e"},// and show the last part in other column
      {value: "f"},
      {value: "g"},
      {value: "h"}
  ];

  var len = $scope.data.length,
      mid = len / 2;

  $scope.left  = $scope.data.slice(0, mid);  
  $scope.right = $scope.data.slice(mid, len);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1fch1221/3/)

Comment: The best solution I've even seen regarding this issue. You saved me minutes of dev. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 15):

There is even a cleaner and simpler solution, but you must use angular 1.2.1: https://jsfiddle.net/1fch1221/6/

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div class="left">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="$index < (data.length / 2)">{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="$index >= (data.length / 2)">{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mikey for example, if data contains more then 8 elements, how do you solve this problem ? always change  $index, it is not good solution and it is not cleaner and simpler solution!

Comment: @Alexander You are right if it comes to a dynamic or unknown amount of items in a list. The problem at hand has a predefined amount of items in the list and that is what my answer is based up on. Just giving OP a solution for what OP asks. And with cleaner I mean a more angular way of dividing the list.

Comment: POST EDIT: Can now handle a dynamic number of elements. The content inside ng-if is just javascript, so changed from a hard coded number. Added a comment here, as otherwise the above comments make no sense.

Comment: @Mikey if you compare to above solution, your answer is much better(maybe my preference). But i like above and yours both solution preferably your one more!

Comment: @Danish Thanks for the compliment. Appreciate the the comment. Keeps me sharp to give clever solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is it cleaner than the other answers, but as idea:

```
ng-repeat="item in data.slice(0, data.length / 2)"
ng-repeat="item in data.slice(data.length / 2, data.length)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest solution here is to divide your data array into 2 different variables. If you cannot do that, you can also code a test function which decide to show or not the given value.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-show="test(item.value)"
```

The JSFiddle of my suggestion : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1fch1221/2/)